# Access individual fields from request body inside cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm sending a post request to a cloud function which contains the following body:

```
{message: "this is the message"}
```

If I try to print the entire body of the request, it shows it, but if I try to get the `message` field, I get `undefined` in the console.

Here's my function:

```
exports.myCloudFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req: any, res: any) => {
    console.log(req.body)\\prints the body of the request fine
    console.log(req.body.message)\\prints "undefined"
    cors(req, res, () => {
        const pl = req.body.message;
        console.log(pl);\\prints "undefined"
    });
    return res.send("all done")
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally haven't worked with firebase before, but from your code and the fact that `req.body` prints the body, it seems that you probably need to parse the request-body as json in order to be able to access the `message` property:

```
const body = JSON.parse(req.body);
console.log(body.message);
```

It could also be the case that you need to setup a bodyparser for `json` content. In a normal express-app you can do this using (note that you don't need the manual parsing from above anymore using bodyparser):

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json();
```

---

EDIT:
see Doug's answer for the correct way to do this, i.e. to fix your request and set the content-type to `application/json` in order for Cloud Functions to automatically parse and populate `req.body` with the request body.

Comment: Adding the code in your first block results in this:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 2
>      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

I'm not sure how to use the bodyParser object. Do I replace JSON.parse(req.body) with JSON.bodyParser(req.body) ?

Comment: Can you try to send valid json with quotes, i.e.: `{"message": "this is the message"}`  ?

Comment: I tried it both ways. This is what you get without the quotes: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 11
>      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Heeey! it works, with the quotes.. but you have to use the double quotes on both sides..

Comment: There is no need for a body parser in Cloud Functions.  The only thing you need is to set the content type to application/json in the request, and Cloud Functions will parse automatically.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a body parser for Cloud Functions as described in the other answer here.  Cloud Functions will [automatically parse JSON](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_content_types) and put the parsed JSON object in the `body` attribute.  If you want this to happen automatically, you should set the content type of the request to "application/json" as described in the linked documentation.  Then you can use `req.body` as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just convert the request body into a JSON object in cloud function.

```
const body = JSON.parse(req.body);
// message
console.log(body.message)
```